# Django logging in and out - doesn't work if prepend_www set

Tags: django, authentication

I'm a Django beginner.

My site - let's call it abc.com - works fine, letting users log in and out (having originally registered via Django registratiaon). If it's relevant, my virtuahosts file has ServerName abc.com and ServerAlias www.abc.com directives.

I don't want my visitors to sense that both abc.com and www.abc.com exist, and so discovered Django's prepend_www setting, which works as intended. In addition to working as intended, however, there's a side effect that disables logging in and out when visiting the www. variant of my site.

Comment: What do you mean by 'disables logging in an out'? What happens when you try?

Comment: When you try to log in on the www. flavor of the site, you simply stay on the home page, no messages, as if you typed in the login details incorrectly. I guess I could get around this by writing some middleware that does the reverse of prepend_www - that is, take people who visit www.abc.com to abc.com, where login functionality works.

All the same, it would be good to understand what's really happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.py try setting:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".abc.com"
```

This will make the cookie apply to all the subdomains of abc.com.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Ned, very much appreciated. Cant upvote - no rep ;-(